# A Sobolev type inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Does there exist a constant $C >0$ such that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} |\nabla w(x)|^2 dx + \int_{\mathbb R^2} w(x)^2\frac{1}{1+|x|^2} dx \geq C \left(\int_{\mathbb R^2} w(x)^6 dx\right)^{\frac 13},$$
for any function $w \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$?

This inequality appears in my recent research. Does anyone know it or have references for it?

Thanks,

Comment: These type of inequalities are called *scale invariant family of Sobolev inequalities*. Look at this paper (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~lsc/sprgsobc.pdf) for definitions and some more. I don't have a reference for the above result.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: Thanks for your comment. However, this inequality is not scale invariant.

Comment: Take $w=1$ in the disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin and then descend to $0$ within the disk of radius $2R$ keeping the gradient of order $1/R$. Then it looks like the LHS is approximately $1+\log R$ while the RHS is $R^{2/3}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fedja: Thanks for your comments. After posting this question, I realized that it does not hold in general. The argument is simple as follows. If there exists $C$, then for any $w$, applying the inequality for $w_a(x) = w(x-a)$, and letting $a\to \infty$ then the integral involving to $w_a^2$ tends to zero. Hence we get
$$\int |\nabla w|^2 dx \geq C \left(\int w^6 dx\right)^{\frac 13},$$
for any $w\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$. The last inequality does not hold because of lossing the scale invariant.